# Joining three different tables with date columns and group by date

Tags: sql, postgresql, date, join

I'm currently working with three different tables that look like this

user:

```
user_id|createtime
-----------------------------
001     2016-07-20
002     2016-08-15
003     2016-08-05
004     2016-08-23
```

object:

```
objc_id|createtime|user_id
-----------------------------
001     2016-07-20   001
002     2016-07-15   001
003     2016-08-05   002
004     2016-08-23   001
005     2016-08-19   003
006     2016-08-21   004
007     2016-08-22   004
```

event:

```
event_id|createtime|objc_id
-----------------------------
001      2016-08-25   001
002      2016-08-26   004
003      2016-08-28   002
004      2016-08-27   005
005      2016-08-30   003
```

I've already made select statements which tell me how many new users, objects or events were created on a certain date:

```
select createtime, count(user_id) as new_user from 
user where createtime >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days' group by
createtime;

select createtime, count(objc_id) as new_objc from 
object createtime >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days' group by createtime;

select createtime, count (event_id) from 
event where createtime >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days' 
group by createtime;
```

Now I want make one select statement, where all the numbers of new objects, users, and events are shown and group them by their creationtime.

However I can't get a solution for this. The goal to achieve would look something like this:

```
createtime|new_user|new_objc|new_event
---------------------------------------
2016-07-15              1
2016-07-20    1         1
2016-07-22    
2016-07-24
2016-08-05    1         1
2016-08-15    1
2016-08-19              1
2016-08-21              1
2016-08-22              1
2016-08-23    1         1
2016-08-25                      1
2016-08-26                      1
2016-08-27                      1
2016-08-28                      1
2016-08-30                      1
```

... also, of course some dates could appear more than once for one group, so that the count will be 1 or higher.

The goal is to see if marketing increases the number of new users, buying of objects and attending to an event over time (you need the object for the event).

Has anybody a solution for this, or do I have to go with separate result tables?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
SELECT
    Createtime
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT user_id) as new_user
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT objc_id) as new_objc
    ,COUNT(DISTINCT new_event) as new_objc
FROM (
    SELECT Createtime, user_id, CAST(NULL AS INT) as objc_id, CAST(NULL as INT) as event_id
    FROM
       users
    WHERE createtime >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Createtime, CAST(NULL AS INT) as user_id, objc_id, CAST(NULL as INT) event_id
    FROM
       object
    WHERE createtime >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days'
    UNION ALL
    SELECT Createtime, CAST(NULL AS INT) as user_id, CAST(NULL AS INT) as objc_id, event_id
    FROM
       event
    WHERE createtime >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days'
) t
GROUP BY
    Createtime
ORDER BY
    Createtime
```

When you first look at your question it looks like you need a join but the reality is you need to union all and count().  I am counting DISTINCT which should be redundant because user_id, objc_id, event_id appear to be unique primary keys.

Answer (score 0):

if you don't want to use your queries try this:

```
SELECT T1.createtime , COUNT(U.user_id) new_user ,
       COUNT(O.objc_id) new_objc , COUNT(E.event_id) new_event
FROM (((SELECT distinct createtime from user
        WHERE createtime >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days'
        UNION
        SELECT distinct createtime from object
        WHERE createtime >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days'
        UNION
        SELECT distinct createtime from event
        WHERE createtime >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days'
        ) as T1 
        LEFT JOIN user U ON T1.createtime = U.createtime)
        LEFT JOIN object O ON O.createtime = T1.createtime)
        LEFT JOIN join event E ON E.createtime = T1.createtime)
GROUP BY T1.createtime ORDER BY T1.createtime;
```

Comment: so because you derive t1 from the tables the full outer join will mean there is never a right outer result returned but LEFT JOIN would be more appropriate.  Also to limit the createtime in a large dataset should preform better if you do it in your union statements.

Comment: @Matt that's right, about limiting createtime in the large dataset, editing now.

Comment: The version works great as well, however I changed the T2.createtime to T1 and an order by T1.createtime for a better overview. Thank you very much for your help!

Answer (score -1):

Use your three select statements as subqueries in an extended join.

```
SELECT A.createtime, A.new_user, B.new_objc, C.new_event 
FROM (
    select createtime, count(user_id) as new_user from 
    user where createtime >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days' group by
    createtime;
) A INNER JOIN (
    select createtime, count(objc_id) as new_objc from 
    object createtime >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days' group by createtime;
) B ON A.createtime = B.createtime INNER JOIN (
    select createtime, count (event_id) as new_event from 
    event where createtime >= CURRENT_DATE - INTERVAL '30 days' 
    group by createtime;
) C ON B.createtime = C.createtime
```

Comment: What if there is a creation time that is missing from users that is in object or event?  This will remove those results.